# How to disable open map messages after every quest in WoW

Tags: world-of-warcraft

After completing every quest, I get a message on screen telling me to open the map, which is very annoying. I have tried looking for an option to disable this behavior but so far I have had no luck (although I must say I have been playing this game for about an hour).

Can this be disabled? If it helps, I am currently playing Mists of Pandaria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it: Open the menu (**Esc** by default), then select **Interface** > **Help** > Untick the **Tutorial** checkbox. This actually disables all popups, not only those related to the map.

Answer (score 2):

The settings tab has been updated. You can now find the setting under **Interface** > **Display**. Then **untick Tutorials**.

Comment: I've purged the comments since it's just you two bickering, so just drop this you two.